# Emacs - intercept file before it is open with external program and modify it, then open modified verison

Tags: emacs

I need to process a file of certain types with external command line program accepting single argument (filename) and then use file modified by this program either open modified file or accept output of command line program as data source for file.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want this to work when you open the file with <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>, then you can probably just attach your behaviour to `find-file`, but deeper down I believe `insert-file-contents` is what eventually reads files in.

A cursory look doesn't seem to show any appropriate hook, so you could look at doing this with before advice.

```
(defadvice insert-file-contents
  (before my-before-insert-file-contents-advice)
  "Process files externally before reading them."
  (let ((filename (expand-file-name (ad-get-arg 0))))
    (message "About to read file %s" filename)
    ;; your code here.

    ;; ;; stupid unsafe example:
    ;; (let ((file (shell-quote-argument filename))
    ;;       (tempfile (shell-quote-argument (make-temp-file "some-prefix-"))))
    ;;   (shell-command (format "sort %s >%s" file tempfile))
    ;;   (shell-command (format "mv %s %s" tempfile file)))
    ))
(ad-activate 'insert-file-contents)
```

You might like to elaborate on your requirements, in case you don't actually need to clobber the original file? (which I think is a horrendous idea, frankly; I certainly wouldn't use code like this!)

For example, you could read in the original file, process it within the buffer (maybe using shell-command-on-region with the replace flag), and set the buffer as unmodified. That way you are only likely to save the changes made by the shell command if you make other edits to the file, and the mere act of loading the file into an editor hasn't actually modified it.

In any case, I trust you'll implement sensible backup processes into your code, and will be plenty paranoid when testing!

Answer (score 3):

Where I used to work there were some binary files that I wanted to view in emacs.  The way I did this was to add to `jka-compr-compression-info-list` like the following for editing applescripts:

```
(add-to-list 'jka-compr-compression-info-list
             ["\\.scpt\\'"
              "Compiling" "osacompile-helper.sh" nil
              "Decompiling" "osacompile-helper.sh" ("-d")
              nil nil "Fasd"])
(jka-compr-update)
```

Here `osacompile-helper.sh` is just a little shell wrapper around `osacompile` and `osadecompile` that reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout` (which is required).  You also need to turn on `auto-compression-mode`, although I think that's the default.  If you use the customize interface to change `jka-compr-compression-info-list`, instead of setting it directly, then you don't have to call `jka-compr-update`.

Comment: This is the right way to do it and it's the way things like opening `.gz` files etc. work.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the external program with `shell-command`, with the output directed to a new buffer. A minimal working example is:

```
(defun my-find-and-process-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((file (read-file-name "File name: "))
         (buf (pop-to-buffer file)))
    (shell-command (format "cat %s" file) buf)))
```

Replace `cat` with the name of your program. This will create a buffer and fill it with the output of your program. If a buffer with the name of your file already exists, it will over-write it. If that's a possibility, you will want to change the buffer name to something safe by adding a suffix or something. This code also doesn't trigger any of the find-file hooks, so you'll have to manually select the mode, or modify the code to do that for you.